# Style/ConditionalAssignment: Use the return of the conditional for variable assignment and comparison

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, conditional-operator, rubocop

Below is my Ruby on Rails code -

```
inactive_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
raw_data = []

data = {
  name: "Test",
  full_name: "Test data"
}
if inactive_list.include? <<id of data>>
  data[:active] = false
else
  data[:active] = true
end

raw_data << data
```

I am getting Rubocop linting error for if...else statement. I tried making several changes but unable to fix linting Rubocop error.

```
C: Style/ConditionalAssignment: Use the return of the conditional for variable assignment and comparison.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of

```
if inactive_list.include? <<id of data>>
  data[:active] = false
else
  data[:active] = true
end
```

you can just write

```
data[:active] = !inactive_list.include? <<id of data>>
```

Or when you are using Rails then you can use `exclude?` instead of the negation of `include?`:

```
data[:active] = inactive_list.exclude? <<id of data>>
```

Full example:

```
data = {
  name: "Test",
  full_name: "Test data",
  active: inactive_list.exclude?(<<id of data>>)
}
```

Comment: `exclude?` is not in ruby, so maybe add a note about this, for future readers?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Directly using `active: inactive_list.exclude?(<<id of data>>) `is really very elegant way of handling the logic!

Answer (score 6):

In general, `Style/ConditionalAssignment` rubocop rule (cop) requires you to change these 2 repetitive assignments:

```
if condition
  variable = value1
else
  variable = value2
end
```

to a single conditional assignment:

```
variable = if condition
             value1
           else
             value2
           end
```

In your case, the *smallest* change Rubocop requires is to change this:

```
if inactive_list.include? <<id of data>>
  data[:active] = false
else
  data[:active] = true
end
```

to that:

```
data[:active] = if inactive_list.include? <<id of data>>
                  false
                else
                  true
                end
```

See @spickermann's answer for a shorter and more elegant further change, which is possible because `include?` returns `true` or `false`, which happens to be exactly what you need for the assignment. So you do not need to explicitly assign `true` or `false` here, just negate it using `!`, a common programming idiom:

```
data[:active] = !inactive_list.include? <<id of data>>
```

---

**SEE ALSO:**

Array `include?` method: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

`RuboCop::Cop::Style::ConditionalAssignment` : https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/ConditionalAssignment

*Check for if and case statements where each branch is used for assignment to the same variable when using the return of the condition can be used instead.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!